# gdb запись по произвольному адресу

Tags: база-данных, stm32, arm

пытаюсь записать число в память устройств 
получается записать в переменную: (gdb)p var=0

читать из памяти: (gdb)x 0x20000000

но как записать в память 4 байта ?
например записать в регистр перефирии

Comment: print *0x20000050=0 (писать по адресу)

Comment: или так set *0x20000050=1